# How do I sort a pandas dataframe by a datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a column in my csv file that I want to have sorted by the datetime. It's in the format like 2020-10-06 03:28:00. I tried doing it like this but nothing seems to have happened.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.sort_index()
df.to_csv('btc.csv', index= False)
```

I need to have that index= False in the .to_csv so that it is formatted properly for later so I can't remove that if that is causing an issue. The dtime is my first column in the csv file and the second column is a unix timestamp so I could also use that if it would work better.

Comment: `df = df.sort_values('second_column_name')`.

Answer (score 0):

`sort_values(by=column_name)` to sort pandas. DataFrame by the contents of a column named column_name . Before doing this, the data in the column must be converted to datetime if it is in another format using `pandas. to_datetime(arg)` with `arg` as the `column of dates.`